# Avoid crashing when class dependency is not present

Tags: java, reflection, crash, dependencies

I've got a project that runs in two different scenarions:

1. My package is present and it's alone
2. My package is present and there's another package PK present

In my project, I have a classes that extends, depends and imports from PK.

- When I execute in the scenario **2**, everything runs fine, and there's no issues on that.
- But when I execute the environment in the scenario **1**, I get `NoClassDefFoundError` due to not resolved classpath.

The problem is that I only know if the other package is present or not at runtime, and I can't change the classpath.

Does anyone know how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I have a class that's the entry point to my execution environment, and my package is called from a proccess that's already running. When my class get's invoked, it checks for each of it's fields to do annotation processing, so any declared fields, even if they're never instantiated, that extends or depends on those classes that are not there will cause everything to fail.

The solution was to move everything to an abstraction layer that will handle the dealing with that package or not, and I've moved everything to that class, avoiding then the field checking, and thus the crash.

Answer (score 1):

try this to check if class is in classpath

```
 try {
    Class.forName("my.package.Foo");
    // it exists on the classpath
 } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
  // it does not exist on the classpath
 }
```

Comment: That was not the issue, I'll explain in my answer.